# Url.Link(): Route cannot be found when using attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

The following exception is thrown on `Url.Link(...)`:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A route named 'api/companies/{companyId:Guid}' could not be found in the route collection.
```

Here is the controller method:

```
[Route("api/companies/")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create()
{
    Company company = new Company("Test!");

    CompanyRepository.Add(company);

    return Created(new Uri(Url.Link("api/companies/{companyId:Guid}", new { companyId = company.Id })), company);
}
```

The route is defined here using attribute routing:

```
[Route("api/companies/{companyId:Guid}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid companyId)
{
    return Ok(CompanyRepository.Find(companyId));
}
```

**Why is it not able to find the route?**  Do I need to use conventional routing in the `RouteConfig`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to name your route like this:

```
[Route("api/companies/{companyId:Guid}", Name="MyRouteName")]
```

and then use

```
Url.Link("MyRouteName", new { companyId = company.Id })
```